# Oracle view, break down values in 0.5 segments

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I need to create an oracle view that will break down data in segments of 0.5 based on a length from a table.

| Road ID | Road Miles |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.4 |

Above is an example of table. The Road Miles is 1.4 miles. I would like to break this down in to 3 rows in segments of 0.5 as shown below.

| Road ID | Beg MP | End MP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 0.5 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 1.0 | 1.4 |

The last row as shown should be the remainder. If the Road Miles was 1.6, then there will be 4 rows.

Is what I am asking possible?
I have used the (trunc) function but it doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**`hierarchical query`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E) such that

```sql
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_road_partition AS
 SELECT Road_ID, .5*(level-1) AS Beg_Mp, LEAST(.5*level,Road_Miles) AS End_Mp
   FROM t 
CONNECT BY level <= CEIL(Road_Miles/.5)   
    AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR Road_ID = Road_ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3a1880a0a3392289f4790b9c1bfb5d60)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive sub-query (which does not have the overhead of generating a GUID with each row):

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name (road_id, beg_mp, end_mp) AS
WITH road_splits (road_id, beg_mp, end_mp) AS (
  SELECT road_id, FLOOR(road_miles * 2)/2, road_miles
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT road_id, beg_mp - 0.5, beg_mp
  FROM   road_splits
  WHERE  beg_mp > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY road_id SET order_id
SELECT road_id, beg_mp, end_mp
FROM   road_splits
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Road_ID, Road_Miles) AS
SELECT 1, 1.4  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0.49 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2.01 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the view would output:

> | ROAD_ID | BEG_MP | END_MP |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1.4 |
> | 1 | .5 | 1 |
> | 1 | 0 | .5 |
> | 2 | 0 | .49 |
> | 3 | 2 | 2.01 |
> | 3 | 1.5 | 2 |
> | 3 | 1 | 1.5 |
> | 3 | .5 | 1 |
> | 3 | 0 | .5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=af5a40c596c2a65930ff026ed453e4a8)*

Answer (score 1):

This will need some data to created/generated.
We can do so using level.

One approach can be as follows -

```
with filler_cte (miles) as
(
select 0.5*level miles from dual connect by level<10
), data_cte(id,b_mp) as
(select 1,1.4 from dual union all
select 2,1.9 from dual)
select id as "Road ID",
miles-0.5 as "Beg MP",
case when ceil(miles) = (select ceil(b_mp)
from data_cte d where d.id = a.id) then b_mp
else miles
end as "End MP"
from data_cte a, filler_cte b
where ceil(a.b_mp) > b.miles
order by id, "Beg MP";

   Road ID     Beg MP     End MP
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0         .5
         1         .5          1
         1          1        1.4
         2          0         .5
         2         .5          1
         2          1        1.9
```